# Aiohttp try to get page response with page numbers until hit empty response

Tags: python, json, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I'm trying to have a small function scraping data from a JSON end point,

the url is like https://xxxxxxxx.com/products.json?&page=" which I can insert a page number,

While I was using requests module I just had a while loop and incrementing the page number and break until I get a empty response (which page is empty)

Is there a possible way to do the same thing with aiohttp?

What I only achieved so far is just pre-genenrate certain number of urls and pass it into tasks
Wondering if I can use a loop as well and stop when see empty response

Thank you very much

'''

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def download_one(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            pprint.pprint(await resp.json(content_type=None))


async def download_all(sites):
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(download_one(site)) for site in sites]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main():
    sites = list(map(lambda x: request_url + str(x), range(1, 50)))
    asyncio.run(download_all(sites))
```

'''

Comment: I think the best solution is to collect data with a small batches till some part of batch will be empty

Comment: but you never checked if page content is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of **untested** code. Even if it won't work, it will give you an idea how to do the job

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def download_one(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        resp = await resp.json()
        if not resp:
            raise Exception("No data found") # needs to be there for breaking the loop


async def download_all(sites):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        futures = [download_one(session, site) for site in sites]
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            futures, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION  # will return the result when exception is raised by any future
        )

        for future in pending:
            future.cancel()  # it will shut down all redundant jobs

def main():
    sites = list(map(lambda x: request_url + str(x), range(1, 50)))
    asyncio.run_until_complete(download_all(sites))
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try it